# Calculate the horizontal distance from each tree node

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, formula, family-tree

I'm creating a pedigree tree diagram for breeding rats and I'm having trouble calculating the horizontal distance I need for each tree node since the number of descendants vary or is dynamic.

I found a script that I'm using to draw the tree but it looks like it doesn't have any documentation with it.

#### I need help in this part

```
var node = new Node({
  title: 'M: ' + pair.male + '<br />F: ' + pair.female,
  stage: stage,
  w: NODE_DIMENSIONS.w,
  h: NODE_DIMENSIONS.h,
  x: COORDINATES.x + (INCREMENTS.x * pair.column), // Formula should adjust based on descendants - HELP
  y: COORDINATES.y + (INCREMENTS.y * pair.generation)
}).attach();
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UJcZ/416/) if you would like to mess around with it and the complete code is provided below.

#### HTML

```
<div id="stage"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.node h4 {
  position: static;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

#### Script

```
var stage = $('#stage');

var NODE_DIMENSIONS = { w: 80, h: 80 };
var SEGMENT_DIMENSIONS = { h: 5 };
var COORDINATES = { x: 50, y: 50 };
var INCREMENTS = { x: 200, y: 150 };

// Sample JSON array resulting from an AJAX call.
var mating = [{
  "name": "one",
  "male": 1234,
  "female": 5643,
  "male_lineage": null,
  "female_parent": null,
  "generation": 0,
  "column": 0
}, {
  "name": "two",
  "male": 6737,
  "female": 1627,
  "male_lineage": ["four"],
  "female_parent": null,
  "generation": 0,
  "column": 2
}, {
  "name": "three",
  "male": 9332,
  "female": 6227,
  "male_lineage": ["five", "six"],
  "female_parent": null,
  "generation": 0,
  "column": 3
}, {
    "name": "four",
  "male": 1111,
  "female": 6537,
  "male_lineage": null,
  "female_parent": "one",
  "generation": 1,
  "column": 1
}, {
    "name": "five",
  "male": 8853,
  "female": 3189,
  "male_lineage": null,
  "female_parent": "two",
  "generation": 1,
  "column": 2
}, {
    "name": "six",
  "male": 8853,
  "female": 3189,
  "male_lineage": null,
  "female_parent": "three",
  "generation": 1,
  "column": 3
}];

var m = new Map();

for (var i = 0; i < mating.length; i++) {
  var pair = mating[i];
  var node = new Node({
    title: 'M: ' + pair.male + '<br />F: ' + pair.female,
    stage: stage,
    w: NODE_DIMENSIONS.w,
    h: NODE_DIMENSIONS.h,
    x: COORDINATES.x + (INCREMENTS.x * pair.column), // Formula should adjust based on descendants - HELP
    y: COORDINATES.y + (INCREMENTS.y * pair.generation)
  }).attach();

  var element = {
    "pair": pair,
    "node": node
  };

  m.set(pair.name, element);
}

m.forEach(function(element, key, m) {
  // We are going to create 2 segments

  // First is for the male lineage
  if (element.pair.male_lineage != null) {
    for(var i = 0; i < element.pair.male_lineage.length; i++) {
        new Segment({
        h: SEGMENT_DIMENSIONS.h,
        stage: stage,
        origin: element.node,
        destination: m.get(element.pair.male_lineage[i]).node
      }).attach();
    }
  }

  // Last is the female parent
  if (element.pair.female_parent != null) {
    new Segment({
      h: SEGMENT_DIMENSIONS.h,
      stage: stage,
      origin: element.node,
      destination: m.get(element.pair.female_parent).node
    }).attach();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not use tools like `vis.js` with hierarchical layout? http://visjs.org/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayout.html

Answer (score 2):

Without even attempting *(pardon me ...)* to dive into the whys-and-wherefores of “your” particular problem, I can categorically say that “tree-drawing is an inherently *recursive* problem.”

Furthermore, it is **not** a problem that maps directly to the HTML “DOM.”   (You will have to “deal with the DOM” *after,* not before, you decide “what the tree needs to look like.”)

Generally speaking, tree-painting problems need to work, recursively, from the bottom up:   the lowest non-leaf nodes distribute their leaves equally, then position themselves equidistant between the leftmost and the rightmost of their children, then report *their* width as being equal to the extent of their children’s width.   (This recursive description of the problem then resolves itself, more-or-less satisfactorily, to encompass the entire tree.)

Once you have thus determined how the entire tree *would like* to appear, your next (but, altogether unrelated ...) problem is:   how to manipulate the *DOM*-tree, which is “the thing that more-or-less drives the *browser,”* to actually produce the visual outcome that you want.

*(“Uhh... except on Internet Explorer 8.”)*